# proper spacing in a table in python

Tags: python

```
Animal ID Location1 Location2
a01    2       1
a03    4       4
a02    0       3
 ================================================================================================================
```

so this is the table that i have using the following code:

```
print("Animal ID","Location1","Location2")       
    for k, v in d.items():
        print(k, end='\t')
        print(v.count('s1'), end='\t')
        print(v.count('s2'))
print("============================================================================================================")
```

but as one can see the table is not spaced out properly,how can i fix it to get a table something like this:

```
Animal Id Station 1 Station 2 
a01          2         1 
a02          0         3 
a03          4         4 
==============================================
```

This is the data is anybody wanted to know. It is in the format animal id:data:location

```
a01:01-24-2011:s1 
a03:01-24-2011:s2 
a02:01-24-2011:s2 
a03:02-02-2011:s2 
a03:03-02-2011:s1 
a02:04-19-2011:s2 
a01:05-14-2011:s2 
a02:06-11-2011:s2 
a03:07-12-2011:s1 
a01:08-19-2011:s1 
a03:09-19-2011:s1 
a03:10-19-2011:s2 
a03:11-19-2011:s1 
a03:12-19-2011:s2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [format](http://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) to form output string

```
a = [(i, i+1, i+2) for i in range(1, 20, 3)]

print("Animal ID","Location1","Location2")
for x, y, z in a:
    s = "{:<9} {:^9} {:^9}".format(x,y,z)
    print(s)
```

Comment: using the above i just get  the numbers go 1,2,3 just to next row 4,5,6 and so on

Comment: That's just example. I don't know your actual data.

Comment: i have added it to my question can you look at it and go from there

Comment: Well. Assuming that you have already had a code to fill your dictionary up. Try `s = "{:<9} {:^9} {:^9}".format(k, v.count('s1'), v.count('s2'))"` And print `s`. Do it in your loop.